# Jackcess "NoClassDefFoundError" exception

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans-7, jackcess

I am using jackcess for the conncetivity to my access database. But I am following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.RowIdImpl.compareTo(RowIdImpl.java:113)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$Entry.compareTo(IndexData.java:1838)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$Entry.compareTo(IndexData.java:1646)
    at java.util.Collections.indexedBinarySearch(Collections.java:273)
    at java.util.Collections.binarySearch(Collections.java:259)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$DataPage.findEntry(IndexData.java:2368)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData.findEntryPosition(IndexData.java:722)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData.access$3300(IndexData.java:56)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$EntryCursor.updatePosition(IndexData.java:2133)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$EntryCursor.restorePosition(IndexData.java:2072)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$EntryCursor.restorePosition(IndexData.java:2055)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$EntryCursor.beforeEntry(IndexData.java:2017)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexCursorImpl.findPotentialRow(IndexCursorImpl.java:368)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexCursorImpl.findFirstRowByEntryImpl(IndexCursorImpl.java:262)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexCursorImpl.findFirstRowByEntry(IndexCursorImpl.java:135)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl$DefaultTableFinder.findRow(DatabaseImpl.java:1890)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl$TableFinder.findObjectId(DatabaseImpl.java:1799)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.readSystemCatalog(DatabaseImpl.java:804)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.<init>(DatabaseImpl.java:513)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.open(DatabaseImpl.java:386)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:170)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:193)
    at ass.Access.main(Access.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.builder.CompareToBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 more
```

I have used jdbc but it is not working either. How can solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackcess has a [dependency](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html) on [Jakarta Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).  You need to make sure that the commons lang and the other dependencies are on your classpath.

Comment: Di Macro I have already added commons logging, commons codec, poi, junit, log4j. Its not working. What am I missing?

Comment: commons lang, version 2.0 downloadable at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.0/commons-lang-2.0.jar

Comment: I have added the file commons lang but now I have got this warning log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. What can I do?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318806/log4jwarn-no-appenders-could-be-found-for-logger-running-jar-file-not-web-app for getting rid of that error.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I got Jackcess working, starting with a fresh install of NetBeans 7.4 on Windows 8:

I downloaded the latest Jackcess JAR file via the "Looking for the latest version?" link on [files](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jackcess/files/) page. I saved it in the folder

C:\Users\Public\Java\

As listed on the [Project Dependencies](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html) page for Jackcess, I downloaded the ZIPped binaries for the two required dependencies: [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) v2.x, and [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi) v1.x. I unpacked the ZIP files into the above folder, so it now contained two sub-folders

C:\Users\Public\Java\commons-lang-2.6\
C:\Users\Public\Java\commons-logging-1.1.3\

I launched NetBeans and created a new Project (for a Java Application) named "myJackcessTest". I expanded the Project in the tree view, right-clicked "Libraries", chose "Add JAR/Folder...", and added the three JAR files:

[image: Libraries.png]

Once that was done, I created my little test app...

```java
package myjackcesstest;

import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyJackcessTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Table table = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Database1.accdb")).getTable("Clients");
            System.out.println(String.format("table contains %d row(s)", table.getRowCount()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

...and when I hit <kbd>F6</kbd> it ran fine:

```
run:
table contains 1 row(s)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```