# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder

Tags: java

I have added all the required jar files to the library but it show the following exception
run:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.RowIdImpl.compareTo(RowIdImpl.java:106)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$Entry.compareTo(IndexData.java:2039)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$Entry.compareTo(IndexData.java:1847)
    at java.util.Collections.indexedBinarySearch(Collections.java:226)
    at java.util.Collections.binarySearch(Collections.java:213)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$DataPage.findEntry(IndexData.java:2570)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData.findEntryPosition(IndexData.java:844)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData.access$3700(IndexData.java:47)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$EntryCursor.updatePosition(IndexData.java:2335)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$EntryCursor.restorePosition(IndexData.java:2273)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$EntryCursor.restorePosition(IndexData.java:2256)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexData$EntryCursor.beforeEntry(IndexData.java:2218)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexCursorImpl.findPotentialRow(IndexCursorImpl.java:376)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexCursorImpl.findFirstRowByEntryImpl(IndexCursorImpl.java:282)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.IndexCursorImpl.findFirstRowByEntry(IndexCursorImpl.java:153)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl$DefaultTableFinder.findRow(DatabaseImpl.java:2074)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl$TableFinder.findObjectId(DatabaseImpl.java:1953)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.readSystemCatalog(DatabaseImpl.java:858)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.<init>(DatabaseImpl.java:518)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.open(DatabaseImpl.java:389)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:248)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DefaultJackcessOpener.open(DefaultJackcessOpener.java:38)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference.<init>(DBReference.java:158)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReferenceSingleton.loadReference(DBReferenceSingleton.java:57)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:103)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at billing.Connect.ConnectDB(Connect.java:24)
    at billing.SPSvegetables.<init>(SPSvegetables.java:27)
    at billing.SPSvegetables$35.run(SPSvegetables.java:1390)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.builder.CompareToBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 44 more
```

Comment: You need commons Lang too

Comment: i havve already added it to my libarary

Comment: It is not available when you run your program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jackcess exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450755/jackcess-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try put them all into the lib directory and build path. Or you should check the availability of your jar files.