# How to install pycharm 5.0 in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

Months ago,I installed pycharm 4.5 in Ubuntu(by run /bin/pycharm.sh),it works well.
Now I found 5.0 version is released.I download the .tar.gz file and unzip it.Then I want to install it in the same way.
But a matter is ,although it runs well, in launcher I found the icon of Pycharm becomes a big "?".Also,in terminal,it gives some warn:

> log4j:warn no appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.internalloggerfactory).  log4j:warn please initialize the log4j system properly.

What that mean?and is it the right way to install Pycharm?

Comment: Try to remove the shortcuts and any 4.5 installation and recreate them from scratch.

Comment: @Bakuriu I tried it but failed..

Comment: Start Pycharm 5.0. It'll ask if you want to create a desktop icon. If it doesn't ask,  go to Tools > Create Desktop Entry. It'll create an icon for you on desktop. Move that icon to your launcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before doing any of this, check if you already have a file named `jetbrains-pycharm.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications/` folder. 
If yes, then check which PyCharm version it is related to. If it is related to your older pycharm install, you'll have to create a new `.desktop` file for PyCharm 5.0. If it is related to the PyCharm 5.0 installation folder, just copy that file to desktop and you're good to go.

If not then you can manually create a `.desktop` file for PyCharm and copy that to desktop.

Create a `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` folder. I'm using nano. You can use gedit or vim or any other text editor.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/pycharm.desktop
```

Paste following lines in the file and save it.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PyCharm
Icon pathToPyCharmFolder/pycharm-4.5.4/bin/pycharm.png
Exec="pathToPyCharmFolder/pycharm-4.5.4/bin/pycharm.sh" %f
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
```

Your `Icon` and `Exec` paths will be different from what I've mentioned.

Copy  `pycharm.desktop` to desktop.

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/pycharm.desktop ~/Desktop/
```

This must solve your problem.

Comment: Oh,it looks useful,but how could I solve the log4j warn?does pycharm need it to run properly?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318806/log4jwarn-no-appenders-could-be-found-for-logger-running-jar-file-not-web-app) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685510/log4j-warning-while-initializing).

Comment: Try running `./pycharm.sh` with `sudo`. It might work.

Comment: thanks,maybe it need a log4j and I will try to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the old Pycharm directory and replace it with the new one. Now run pycharm.sh from the termin to start Pycharm. Once opened, go to Tools> Create desktop entry.

Once this is done, close the current instance and now the new icon should appear in the launcher.

Comment: It is already mentioned in a comment.

Comment: @Narendra  I had did that,and it asked me to give a permission to creat a desktop icon,but when that finished,nothing changed on my desktop.

Comment: when you open Pycharm using pycharm.sh, open it with sudo. `sudo ./pycharm.sh` This should solve it @DavidPage

Comment: @BansalUtkarsh  but I tried out sudo,it is no use..

Comment: You probably have an old `jetbrains-pycharm.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/` folder related to older PyCharm install. That's why new `.desktop` file creation is failing.