# Log4J: Warn No Appenders could be found for Logger error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, log4j

Below is my log4j.properties file content, file is placed with the src folder in eclipse.

```
#Application Logs
log4j.rootlogger=INFO, logg
log4j.appender.logg=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logg.File=D:\\SandhyaFiles\\SeleniumWorkspace\\InterviewProject\\Logs\\Testlogs.log
log4j.appender.logg.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout


log4j.appender.logg.layout.ConversionPattern=%d -%c -%p - %m%n
log4j.appender.logg.maxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.logg.maxBackupIndex=3
```

Inside Library package i have initialised and used logj as below:

```
public class Library
{

  public static final Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(Library.class);

  public void initialized(){

  Log.info("Inside initialise")
}}
```

calling initialize from testcase throws log4j warning:

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (library.Library).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Please Help me fix this.

Comment: Are you sure the log4j property file is also on the classpath?

Comment: I have added log4j jar file in java build path as an external jar file.

Comment: Have you searched other answers? Some solutions: [properly ensure its in class path through Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25163361/2173960), [pass config file as parameter when running program](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11318951/2173960).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After so many trials, weirdly re arranging the properties file to this everything is going no warning and could get the logs.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, logg

log4j.appender.logg=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logg.File=.\\Logs\\Testlogs.log
log4j.appender.logg.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.logg.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.logg.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logg.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I wonder why this is so? if somebody can explain it will be great help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It seems like log4j is not able to find the log4j properties file.

One could specify the location of the log4j.properties file explicitly via the `log4j.configuration` system property.

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:mylogging.properties
```

In case the system property `log4j.configuration` is not defined, then the resource is set to its default value `log4j.properties` and looked for in the classpath of the project (at root).

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting. Been struggling with this for an hour and this was the only solution that provided any logging (checked several SO posts + the provided log4j link) - it's an old project so wasn't really interested pulling it apart to see what the exact problem was.